# Force a RewriteRule pointing CSS files to PHP, into sub-directories containing an .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an .htaccess file in a folder redirecting all CSS and JS files to a php file.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.(js|css)) process.php?file=$1
```

And it works fine into sub-directories as well, however I have a sub-directory containing an .htaccess file with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

For the purpose of using "clean URLs"

How can I force this sub-directory to still send the CSS/JS files through what's defined in the parent directory?

I know I can manually do this for that sub-directory by placing exception within the sub-directory's .htaccess file - but can I do it any other way?

This is for distribution so it will be a hell of a lot easier if I can somehow force the parent RewriteRule into all sub-directories regardless.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You can try placing this line in subdirectory's .htaccess just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteOptions inherit
```

Comment: I already know that would work, but I want to see if it would be possible without adding that to an .htaccess file in the sub-directory.

Comment: No it won't work without this as sub directory's .htaccess overrides parent's rules.